# Installing Ubuntu v12 on computer running Windows ME

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows

I want to put Ubuntu on a computer running Windows ME.I have the Ubuntu CD that I purchased, but my computer will not boot to this disc. I can see the disc on my "D" drive and when I click on the installer nothing happens. It will not open the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your computer will boot from a CD?

Typically you need to hit F2 or some other F key while the computer is booting to get into the BIOS set-up. Somewhere in there will be a 'boot sequence' configuration. Make sure the CD drive is set to boot before the hard drive, then reboot.